# What's the difference between a += number and a += number, (with a trailing comma) when a is a list?

Tags: python, list, tuples, extend

I am reading a snippet of Python code and there is one thing I can't understand. `a` is a list, `num` is an integer

```
a += num,
```

works but

```
a += num
```

won't work. Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it is important to note here that `a += 1,` works differently than `a = a + 1,` in this case. (`a = a + 1,` and `a = a + (1,)` are both throwing a `TypeError` because you can't concatenate a list and a tuple, but you you can *extend* a list with a tuple.)

`+=` calls the lists `__iadd__` method, which calls `list.extend` and then returns the original list itself.

`1,` is a tuple of length one, so what you are doing is

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.extend((1,))
>>> a
[1]
```

which just looks weird because of the length one tuple. But it works just like extending a list with a tuple of any length:

```
>>> a.extend((2,3,4))
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you timgeb! This is really helpful! I thought a +=1, is equivalend to a = a+ (1,) and apparently this is not how python works.

Comment: @yuhengd yeah lists do "that" and the fact is not really well documented.

Answer (score 3):

The trailing comma makes the right side of the assignment into a *tuple*, not an integer. A tuple is a container structure similar to a list (with some differences).  For example, these two are equivalent:

```
a += num,
a += (num, )
```

Python allows you to add a tuple to a list and will append each element of the tuple to the list. It doesn't allow you to add a single integer to a list, you have to use append for that.

Answer (score 2):

using

```
num,
```

declares a tuple of length one, and not an integer.

Thus, if a = [0,1] and num = 2

```
a+=num,
```

is equivalent to

```
a.extend((num,))
```

or

```
a.extend((2,))=[0,1,2]
```

while

```
a+=num
```

is equivalent to

```
a.extend(num)
```

or

```
a.extend(2)
```

which gives an error, because you can append a tuple to an array, but not an integer. Thus the first formulation works while the second gives you an error

Comment: The quirk here is that `a+=num,` is *not* equivalent to `a=a+(num,)`, the second one throws a `TypeError`. The first one does not because internally `+=` uses `list.extend`.

Comment: thanks, this indeed made my answer quite misleading. I modified it.

Comment: Also note that `extend` returns `None`, so your assigment assigns to `None`.